# Landscape imageview overlap toolbar and statusbar

Tags: android, imageview

I have an imageview which is displayed in center of the screen. In portrait mode it displays fine but when i rotate screen in horizontal mode then imageview is opelapping my toolbar and status bar like in screenshot attached below. I tried couple of settings but it didn't change anything. I tired below toolbar option but it will attach imagview after toolbar but i need to display imageview in center.So I need a help to fix this laypout.Here is my layout xml code.

```
Imageview layout:

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".DetailActivity"
    >

    <include android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar"/>


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:transitionName="photo_hero"
        android:id="@+id/image"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

toobal layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark" >
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

screenshot:

http://s9.postimg.org/6lyxbaq27/landscape_problem.png
http://s9.postimg.org/n8ghkdizz/landscape_problem_2.png

Comment: This is how RelativeLayout works, read documentation!

Comment: I am new to android.Please guide to right code to make it work Viktor

Comment: Use LinearLayout with orientation = "vertical" to make views go one after another

Answer (score 0):

Put this:

```
android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
```

inside of your `<ImageView>` tag.

It should look like:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:transitionName="photo_hero"
    android:id="@+id/image"
    />
```

Comment: Thankx but this doesn't solve my problem as i have mentioned in my question i user below toolbar option.Sorry i didn't wrote ir properly.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of relative layout try to use Frame Layout like:-

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_parent_view"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:transitionName="photo_hero"
    android:id="@+id/image"
    />
</LinearLayout>
 <include layout="@layout/toolbar"/>
```

Comment: are you sure he wants to overlap an image with toolbar? three overdraws here - window + imageview+toolbar+toolbars elements

Comment: Thankx @Adarsh Yadav.I tried your solution but now the toolbar overlaps my imageview and it's not centered horizontally either :)

Answer (score 0):

As Viktor suggested. I used linearlayout with orientation vertical and with few parameter changes in my imageview.Here is the final code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".DetailActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <include android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar"/>


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```